# How to create new worksheet based on filter value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

As you see below screenshot, I have a workbook with all user's information(left screenshot) . I would like to make separate worksheet based on name of team lead(right screenshot). My problem is team lead column value is always changed because I run a report from an application.

but my actual code looks :

```
Range("A:D").AutoFilter Field:=4, Array("Marth", "Rick", "Georgia")
```

It would be appreciated if anyone could help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using an Array to filter multiple results, use the 3rd parameter of `Operator:=xlFilterValues`.

Try the line below:

```
Range("A:D").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("Marth", "Rick", "Georgia"), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 0):

This code filters the source data (sheet1) for the first criteria "marth" and copy/pasting into the "marth" worksheet.

To complete the code you would need to build it out for each sheet by adding additional steps to filter,copy and paste.  Good Luck!

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter

'identifiers that need to be filtered from the full report
ActiveSheet.Range("A:D").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
Array("Marth"), Operator:=xlFilterValues


'columns that need to be brought from full report to the group tab
Range("A:D").Copy

'update for the sheet you are pasting to
Sheets("Marth").Select

Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```